# How do I include "{% %}" in markdown file when using jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I am using Jekyll to post blogs. When I write "{%...%}" in my markdown files, it seems that the "{%...%}" will be parsed by Liquid. But sometimes that is not what I want, and may cause errors. So what's the proper way to include texts like "{%...%}" in my post content(the .md file)?

I checked the Liquid docs and learned I can use the Block Tag `{% raw %} ... {% end raw %}` to include raw text between. However, I don't think this a good idea. Because if the markdown file was not parsed by Liquid (e.g., in some environment other than Jekyll), this will leave unused {% raw %} in my text.

Correct me if I said something wrong.

P.S.: I use GitHub Pages for hosting and they disable plugins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing to remember about Jekyll and GitHub pages is that you can *always* build your site locally (by running `jekyll build`), commit it to your repo and have GitHub serve it from there. So you can use (or create) a plugin that'll enable you to have what you want. :P

On the other hand, I think it's really too much trouble to not use the `{% raw %}`. If -- and only if -- you're going to use these markdown files somewhere else, you can pass them through a script (or a `sed` command) and sweep away these tags.

Comment: Finally I decided to use the `{% raw %}` in the post. And as you said, if I am going to use the markdown files somewhere else, I will modify them. Thank you, @agarie.

Answer (score 1):

You could use HTML entities `&#123;` and `&#125;` for `{` and `}`. Not the tidiest but it doesn't use `{% raw %}` or rely on plugins.

Comment: Note that this won't work inside a markown code block (it will display `&#123;` rather than displaying an open bracket).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using the following code:

```
{% capture sidebar %}{% include sidebar.md %}{% endcapture %}
{{ sidebar | markdownify }}
```

It the above snippet I am including a sidebar that I wrote in Markdown.

Here is a link to the original [GitHub comment](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1303#issuecomment-21067548) where I got this idea from.